# Varias consultas un solo resultado mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Amigos tengo que de una tabla el poder traer cuales son los estudiantes que estan activos y cual es su acudiente, para esto se tiene dos tabla una llamada usuario y otra user_rel que tiene la relacion padre estudiante, bueno ya puedo obtener cuales son padres con hijos según esa relacion, lo que obtengo es:

```
+------------+------------+
| P          | E          |
+------------+------------+
| 10102076   | 27704432   |
| 10102076   | 27704433   |
| 10245781   | 27187347   |
| 10245781   | 27682988   |
| 10276256   | 28507234   |
| 1129577148 | 1044216267 |
| 12622029   | 39510313   |
| 13361988   | 27758745   |
| 13481465   | 30407052   |
| 13808810   | 646        |
+------------+------------+
```

Mi codigo con el que lo obtengo es:

```
SELECT user_rel.id_parent AS P, user_rel.id_student AS E FROM user_rel WHERE user_rel.id_student IN 
(
SELECT  
usuario.Idcust
FROM usuario WHERE active = 0 AND idprofile = 2
) ;
```

Mi tabla usuario es la siguiente, donde para diferenciar el estudiante del padre es por `idprofile` donde 2 es estudiante y 3 es padre:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Idcust         | varchar(50)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Name           | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| FLastName      | varchar(200) | YES  |     |         |       |
| SLastName      | varchar(200) | YES  |     |         |       |
| Sex            | varchar(10)  | YES  |     |         |       |
| birdthdate     | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Course         | int(2)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| idtype         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email          | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |    
| active         | int(1)       | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| idprofile      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |    
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Se que para esto se ha de necesitar varias consultas, pero no he podido hacer la integración como tal, veran ya que tengo el primer resultado, de la user_rel obtengo los resultados por separados, como veran tendria que mostrarlo de esta forma, alguien podria ayudarme con esto:

```
+--------+--------------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+
| ID     | Nombre Estudiante  | Apellido Estudiante | DOC   |  Nombre Padre | Apellido  |
+--------+--------------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+
| 1233   | Pepito             | Plus                | 12345 | Pepo          |   Plus    |
| 1233   | Pepito             | Plus                | 12345 | Pepo          |   Plus    |
| 1233   | Pepito             | Plus                | 12345 | Pepo          |   Plus    |
| 1233   | Pepito             | Plus                | 12345 | Pepo          |   Plus    |
+--------+--------------------+---------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar la estructura de las tablas para ver las relaciones de los Primary Key y Foreign Key?

Comment: directamente no se trabaja con un Foreign Key, por que no se asi lo tienen

Comment: A ver si entendí bien: tienes una tabla donde están los padres y los hijos y quieres obtener una lista donde aparezca el hijo en una columna y quién es su padre en otra columna. ¿Es eso?

Comment: @A.Cedano siii exactamente

Comment: Bien bien, pero me perdí con lo que dices de tu tabla `user_rel` ¿? ¿Esa tabla ya expresa la relación padres-hijos? ¿Cuál es la estructura de esa tabla?

Comment: solo tiene id_parent y id_son

Comment: Más dudas: ¿a qué corresponde la columna `ID` con valor `1233`? ¿Por qué esperas resultados con datos repetidos una y otra vez? ¿Lo que quieres mostrar no es el estudiante y su padre? ¿Por qué entonces varios `Pepito Plus` en los resultados esperados?

Comment: A.Cedano esos datos repetidos son a modo de ejemplo del resultado

Answer (score 0):

Usando como pivote la tabla de relación haz dos JOINs, uno para estudiantes y otro para padres:

```
SELECT ur.id_student
     , e.Name nombre_estudiante
     , e.FLastName apellido_estudiante
     , ur.id_parent
     , p.Name nombre_padre
     , p.FLastName apellido_padre
  FROM user_rel ur
    INNER JOIN usuario e
       ON    e.Idcust = ur.id_student
         AND e.id_profile = 3
    INNER JOIN usuario p
       ON    p.Idcust = ur.id_parent
         AND p.id_profile = 2
  WHERE e.active = 0
```